# Data importation in r by lodown

Tags: r, survey

```
options( survey.lonely.psu = "adjust" )

library(survey)

library(lodown)

# retrieve a listing of all available extracts for the youth risk behavioral 
# surveillance system
yrbss_cat <- get_catalog( "yrbss" , output_dir = file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "YRBSS" ) )

# limit the catalog to only years 2005-2015
yrbss_cat <- subset( yrbss_cat , year %in% seq( 2005 , 2015 , 2 ) )

# download the yrbss microdata
lodown( "yrbss" , yrbss_cat )
```

this code is supposed to download yrbss dataset and convert to rda files, it is not working. Can someone help?

The error is as under

---

> > options( survey.lonely.psu = "adjust" )
> >     library(survey) Loading required package: grid Loading required package: Matrix Loading required package: survival
>
> Attaching package: ‘survey’
>
> The following object is masked from ‘package:graphics’:
>
> ```
> dotchart
> ```
>
> Warning message: package ‘survey’ was built under R version 3.4.4
>
> > library(lodown)
> >
> > ## retrieve a listing of all available extracts for the youth risk behavioral
> >
> > ## surveillance system
> >
> > yrbss_cat <- get_catalog( "yrbss" , output_dir = file.path( path.expand( "~" ) , "YRBSS" ) ) building catalog for yrbss
> >
> > ## retrieve a listing of all available extracts for the youth risk behavioral
> >
> > ## surveillance system
> >
> > yrbss_cat <- get_catalog( "yrbss" , output_dir = file.path( path.expand( "U:/" ) , "YRBSS" ) ) building catalog for yrbss
> >
> > yrbss_cat    directory year                                                             dat_url 1       1991 1991
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/1991/yrbs1991.dat 2       1993 1993 
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/1993/yrbs1993.dat 3       1995 1995 
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/1995/nchrbs1995.dat 4       1995
> >     1995
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/1995/yrbs1995.dat 5       1997 1997 
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/1997/yrbs1997.dat 6       1998 1998 
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/1998/ayrbs1998.dat 7       1999 1999
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/1999/yrbs1999.dat 8       2001 2001 
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2001/yrbs2001.dat 9       2003 2003 
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2003/yrbs2003.dat 10      2005 2005 
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2005/yrbs2005.dat 11      2007 2007 
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2007/yrbs2007.dat 12      2009 2009 
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2009/yrbs2009.dat 13      2011 2011 
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2011/yrbs2011.dat 14      2013 2013 
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2013/yrbs2013.dat 15      2015 2015 
> >     https://www.cdc.gov/healthyyouth/data/yrbs/files/yrbs2015.dat 16
> >     2017 2017 
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/sadc_2017/sadc_2017_district.dat 17 
> >     2017 2017 
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/sadc_2017/sadc_2017_national.dat 18 
> >     2017 2017
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/sadc_2017/sadc_2017_state_a_m.dat 19
> >     2017 2017
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/sadc_2017/sadc_2017_state_n_z.dat
> >                                                                                       sas_url         output_filename 1
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/1991/YRBS_1991_SAS_Input_Program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/1991 main.rds 2
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/1993/YRBS_1993_SAS_Input_Program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/1993 main.rds 3
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/1995/NCHRBS_1995_SAS_Input_Program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/1995 main.rds 4
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/1995/YRBS_1995_SAS_Input_Program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/1995 main.rds 5
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/1997/YRBS_1997_SAS_Input_Program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/1997 main.rds 6
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/1998/AYRBS_1998_SAS_Input_Program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/1998 main.rds 7
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/1999/YRBS_1999_SAS_Input_Program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/1999 main.rds 8
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2001/YRBS_2001_SAS_Input_Program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/2001 main.rds 9
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2003/YRBS_2003_SAS_Input_Program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/2003 main.rds 10
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2005/YRBS_2005_SAS_Input_Program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/2005 main.rds 11
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2007/YRBS_2007_SAS_Input_Program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/2007 main.rds 12
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2009/YRBS_2009_SAS_Input_Program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/2009 main.rds 13
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2011/YRBS_2011_SAS_Input_Program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/2011 main.rds 14
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2013/YRBS_2013_SAS_Input_Program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/2013 main.rds 15
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2015smy/YRBS_2015_SAS_Input_Program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/2015 main.rds 16
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/sadc_2017/2017_sadc_national_sas_input_program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/2017 main.rds 17
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/sadc_2017/2017_sadc_sas_input_program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/2017 main.rds 18
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/sadc_2017/2017_sadc_states_a-m_sas_input_program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/2017 main.rds 19
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/sadc_2017/2017_sadc_states_n-z_sas_input_program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/2017 main.rds
> >
> > ## limit the catalog to only years 2005-2015
> >
> > yrbss_cat <- subset( yrbss_cat , year %in% seq( 2005 , 2015 , 2 ) )
> >     yrbss_cat    directory year                                                       dat_url 10      2005 2005
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2005/yrbs2005.dat 11      2007 2007 
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2007/yrbs2007.dat 12      2009 2009 
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2009/yrbs2009.dat 13      2011 2011 
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2011/yrbs2011.dat 14      2013 2013 
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2013/yrbs2013.dat 15      2015 2015
> >     https://www.cdc.gov/healthyyouth/data/yrbs/files/yrbs2015.dat
> >                                                                          sas_url         output_filename 10
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2005/YRBS_2005_SAS_Input_Program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/2005 main.rds 11
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2007/YRBS_2007_SAS_Input_Program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/2007 main.rds 12
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2009/YRBS_2009_SAS_Input_Program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/2009 main.rds 13
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2011/YRBS_2011_SAS_Input_Program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/2011 main.rds 14
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2013/YRBS_2013_SAS_Input_Program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/2013 main.rds 15
> >     https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2015smy/YRBS_2015_SAS_Input_Program.sas
> >     U://YRBSS/2015 main.rds
> >
> > ## download the yrbss microdata
> >
> > lodown( "yrbss" , yrbss_cat ) locally downloading yrbss
>
> downloading from URL
>   'https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2005/yrbs2005.dat' to file
>   'C:\Users\JAIMIN~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpemmaly\file684c13a73873'
>
> download issue with
>   'https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2005/yrbs2005.dat'
>
> download issue with
>   'https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2005/yrbs2005.dat'
>
> download issue with
>   'https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2005/yrbs2005.dat'
>
> R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21) Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>   Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)
>
> Matrix products: default
>
> locale: [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
>   LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United
>   States.1252 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C
>   LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
>
> attached base packages: [1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices
>   utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages: [1] lodown_0.1.0    survey_3.33-2
>   survival_2.41-3 Matrix_1.2-9
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] httr_1.3.1
>   compiler_3.4.0  R6_2.2.2        tools_3.4.0     RCurl_1.95-4.11
>   curl_2.6        yaml_2.1.14     splines_3.4.0    [9] digest_0.6.16
>   bitops_1.0-6    lattice_0.20-35
>
> lodown is now exiting unexpectedly. websites that host
>   publicly-downloadable microdata change often and sometimes those
>   changes cause this software to break. if the error call stack below
>   appears to be a hiccup in your internet connection, then please verify
>   your connectivity and retry the download. otherwise, please open a new
>   issue at `https://github.com/ajdamico/asdfree/issues` with the
>   contents of this error call stack and also the output of your
>   `sessionInfo()`.
>
> [[1]] lodown("yrbss", yrbss_cat)
>
> [[2]] withCallingHandlers(catalog <- load_fun(data_name = data_name, 
>       catalog, ...), error = function(e) {
>       print(sessionInfo())
>       if (grepl("cannot allocate vector of size", e)) 
>           message(memory_note)
>       else if (grepl("parameter must be specified", e)) 
>           message(parameter_note)
>       else if (grepl("to install", e)) 
>           message(installation_note)
>       else {
>           message(unknown_error_note)
>           print(sys.calls())
>       } })
>
> [[3]] load_fun(data_name = data_name, catalog, ...)
>
> [[4]] cachaca(catalog[i, "dat_url"], tf_fn, mode = "wb")
>
> [[5]] httr_filesize(this_url, attempts, sleepsec)
>
> [[6]] stop(paste0("httr::HEAD( '", url, "' )\nfailed after ",
>   initial.attempts, 
>       " attempts"))
>
> [[7]] .handleSimpleError(function (e)  {
>       print(sessionInfo())
>       if (grepl("cannot allocate vector of size", e)) 
>           message(memory_note)
>       else if (grepl("parameter must be specified", e)) 
>           message(parameter_note)
>       else if (grepl("to install", e)) 
>           message(installation_note)
>       else {
>           message(unknown_error_note)
>           print(sys.calls())
>       } }, "httr::HEAD( 'https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2005/yrbs2005.dat' )\nfailed after
>   3 attempts", 
>       quote(httr_filesize(this_url, attempts, sleepsec)))
>
> [[8]] h(simpleError(msg, call))
>
> Error in httr_filesize(this_url, attempts, sleepsec) :    httr::HEAD(
>   'https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2005/yrbs2005.dat' ) failed after 3
>   attempts    directory year
>   dat_url 10      2005 2005
>   https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2005/yrbs2005.dat 11      2007 2007 
>   https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2007/yrbs2007.dat 12      2009 2009 
>   https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2009/yrbs2009.dat 13      2011 2011 
>   https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2011/yrbs2011.dat 14      2013 2013 
>   https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2013/yrbs2013.dat 15      2015 2015
>   https://www.cdc.gov/healthyyouth/data/yrbs/files/yrbs2015.dat
>                                                                        sas_url         output_filename case_count 10
>   https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2005/YRBS_2005_SAS_Input_Program.sas
>   U://YRBSS/2005 main.rds         NA 11
>   https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2007/YRBS_2007_SAS_Input_Program.sas
>   U://YRBSS/2007 main.rds         NA 12
>   https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2009/YRBS_2009_SAS_Input_Program.sas
>   U://YRBSS/2009 main.rds         NA 13
>   https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2011/YRBS_2011_SAS_Input_Program.sas
>   U://YRBSS/2011 main.rds         NA 14
>   https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2013/YRBS_2013_SAS_Input_Program.sas
>   U://YRBSS/2013 main.rds         NA 15
>   https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2015smy/YRBS_2015_SAS_Input_Program.sas
>   U://YRBSS/2015 main.rds         NA
>   >

Comment: This might be a worth raising as an issue on the github page for the lodown package. I ran your code and got a message about a download issue with 'https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2005/yrbs2005.dat'. I then tried `> download.file("ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/2005/YRBS2005.dat", destfile = "temp.dat")` and was able to download the file without an error. Something about the way that lodown is downloading this file is what I think is causing the error

Comment: hi, what's the error?  and what happens when you use `httr::HEAD( 'https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/1991/yrbs1991.dat' )` ?  thanks

Comment: Anthony I have pasted the console output, also I have pasted the object, which was created properly. I think the issue is with downloading. Thanks for writing lodown code. I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Users should realize that R will "go silent" and appear to "hang" during the process of downloading large files. I was able to monitor the progress on a Mac by looking at the NHANES directory.

Comment: There was a major change in the serialization format between R 3.4 and 3.5. Any possibility that this could explain?

Comment: > httr::HEAD( 'https://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/data/yrbs/1991/yrbs1991.dat' )
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates This is what it says when I run the command that you mentioned.

Comment: library(httr)
set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L)) #these two lines fixes the Peer certificate error and then the code started working. I guess I found solution myself.............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

library(httr) set_config(config(ssl_verifypeer = 0L)) #these two lines fixes the Peer certificate error and then the code started working.